# Should I call out former boss for his unreasonable demands to return the equipment in solely his terms even if I am in no position to do so?

Tags: resignation, startup, bullying, harassment, philippines

**UPDATE: I** had a cousin who invited me to his car ride. We are now bringing over the equipment to the office. We will not leave until we see my former employer. I also have a turnover document with me, which I will make them sign. That and a demand letter for them to pay me. Notarized. Thank you for the help guys, and I apologize for my rude tone.

**I have edited the question to emphasize the important points of my situation. Please bear with me.**

I have officially resigned from the startup I was with.

Needless to say, I need to turnover my equipment immediately. However, I am so financially hard up that I am practically trapped in my house. I cannot give the equipment to my former employer. **Let me emphasize please. I don't. Have. Money.**

(Apparently, it comes across that I do, but no. My internet is prepaid. I have already paid for all my bills. My living expenses have sucked the rest of my funds *before I resigned.* Most importantly, I am actively looking for a job within walking distance from my house)

Yet s/he insists that I return the equipment immediately. Only then s/he will give my salary after a few months.

A few months! I told him/her repeatedly through emails and chat that **I am in no financial position to give the equipment to him/her**. That s/he has to give my money first. Yet s/he insists his/her position. It's as if they chose to be oblivious to the fact that I cannot deliver the equipment to them. Absolutely insensitive and unreasonable!

My government's Department of Labor and Employment mandates that my employer has to pay my salary immediately, no promissory notes, as soon as my contract has ended no matter how it ended. It is *my employer* who should fulfill their end of the bargain first, especially that several days have passed since the supposed payday.

**So I finally offered to invite them to my house, and give them the equipment, but then only after they give me my full salary.** So far no response. I doubt that they have read it. Their domain was suspended.

I'm expecting the worst from them. They will probably visit my house, not bring my salary, barge right in and take the equipment by force. Which is why (I am taking) have already taken the equipment to my village's captain's office (walking distance from my house.) That way they cannot harass me or my family without them facing serious repercussions. **More importantly, so that I can prove to any court that I have no intention of stealing the equipment.**

I am very, very angry at their unprofessional, unreasonable behavior. Especially that they have ignored some of my messages again and again. Should I call them out on this in any correspondence? Or should I just press charges for their lack of response?

Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40196/discussion-on-question-by-jenny-tengson-mandani-should-i-call-out-former-boss-fo).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, "call the manager out?" To whom? What will be the consequences? Will you be awarded compensation, or a letter of apology? Of course not.

I find it hard to believe you have something valuable enough they could ask for it repeatedly, and would just say "hey, I have no car or money for buses, so it will just sit here until someone picks it up." If I was that boss, I would say that I would pay for a cab or a train ticket to bring me the equipment, or I would come for it. If the real issue was money you would ask for such as thing and be granted it. I think your **real** motivation is to **trade it for the salary you are owed**, and to demonstrate your anger.

But here's the thing: the level of anger you have right now, and refusing to meet your obligations because they owe you? It is, as the saying goes, like taking poison and waiting for your enemy to die. Do the right thing, because you are a good person even if they aren't. They will probably never pay you what they owe you. You can't make them do so, either. You have to give up your sense of control over that.

You can't take the equipment to them. I believe that. If they show up and ask for it, well, it's theirs and it's not really a hostage to help you get your pay, much as you would like it to be. If they email and ask for it tell them you cannot bring it to them and it's safe at your house, and by the way, my salary is now X weeks late, when can I expect it? I think if they were going to come for it they would have already, but that's not your problem. You keep asking for your pay and explaining what is physically impossible, but if they show up, you give it to them.

If you're worried they might break into your house I suppose putting the equipment elsewhere is feasible, but on the premise that they can have it if they show up and ask for it. (Also consider how they know you've done that? They might still ransack your house for it.) **You're not a thief.** It's their equipment. You treat them honourably even while they steal from you by withholding what you're owed. They have nothing to threaten you with. Once they have picked up the equipment, you owe them nothing and they can't hold anything over you. Then it is just a Department of Labour matter to get you paid. If you can find a local lawyer who is willing to be paid after winning the case, or a Citizens Advice Bureau who will help you for free, you may be able to get the salary more quickly. Or they may go bankrupt and never pay you. But you will still be yourself and not a thief, and that's important when your back is against the wall.

Comment: Thank you Kate. I cried. You have comforted me with that answer and gave me sense of hope in my situation. Thank you so much.